# Booting Google Coral, unknown-block(179,3) error

Tags: boot, google-coral

I have previously flashed my Google Coral Dev board. I'm trying to boot it up again, but when powering on, it ends on the error message:

```
end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,3)
```

I am following the instructions from [here].(https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/get-started/)

Solutions online address issues with [(179,2)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=12245) and [(179,6)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40854/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block179-6), but I have not found one addressing the (179,3) error.

Comment: Did you try this method too : https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/reflash/#flash-from-u-boot-on-an-sd-card ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you ran into some data transferring issue during the flashing process of the board. My advice is to reflash the board, make sure you use a USB-A - USB-C cable that's capable of data transferring and not just power. Also, make sure your dev board is properly powered.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve above issue using below link

https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0

OR 
Please reboot again with Mendel4.0
https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/reflash/